# Formular for counting names in a spreadsheet which are seperated with , or /

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

so I want to count the names in a cell which are separated with , or / like [that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FSkau.png)

I tried several thing but nothing seems to work and I always get an error, can you help me out?

I tried the following formulas:

> =ArrayFormula(if(len(B457:B),len(B457:B)-len(SUBSTITUTE(B457:B,",",""))+1,))

OR even easier like:
[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7woXJ.png)

> =LEN(TRIM(A1))-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(A1),",",""))+1

It would be enough if it would just count all names separated with **,** ...so we'd just tell people to ad a **,** to separate their names and not a /..but it would be nice if both would work!

Thanks so much in advance!

Best regards
Paul

Answer (score 0):

use semicolon:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(B457:B); LEN(B457:B)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(B457:B; ","; ""))+1; ))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in cell `C457` (removing all content below):

```
=arrayformula(if(B457:B<>"",len(regexreplace(regexreplace(B457:B,"[\/\,]$",),"[^\/\,]+",))+1,))
```

My example sheet screengrab works from row 2:

[image]